# Finding the best locations for bee hives within a specified area (QGIS)

Tags: qgis

I would like to find fixed positions for bee hives within an orchard to ensure complete pollination of the trees. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Example: The orchard area is 2 hectares (I have a polygon dataset representing the orchard). 10 bee hives are required to pollinate the area. How would I go about calculating the best positions for the the bee hives to ensure complete bee coverage of the orchards in QGIS?

Comment: There seems to be a lot more info you need....like how far a bee flies, paths directions......etc. once this is known you would place points at each location, and buffer each point to the distance they would fly, disolve boundaries will expose any "holes".

Comment: @Gerald The only information available to me is the amount of hives required per hectare. I am not a bee expert, but apparently each bee hive will pollinate its 2000 sq meters if placed correctly.  There are about 600 hectares of trees on the clients farm so trying to manually move around points (hive locations) is a last resort.

Comment: http://www.beginningbeekeeping.com/LocatingYourBeehive.html

Answer (score 2):

[image]This was a comment but was getting too long:

god that is a big area with a lot of unknowns. If it was me i would use another programe (AutoCAD) to create an array of circles with an area of 2000sqm each. then over lap them (or not but will be a lot of holes between each circle if not). then pick out the centre points of each and make sure your array is bigger than the area you need.....assuming the 600 ha is not just a square.

import dxf to QGIS. Overlay the area (600ha) onto this. create a shape file of the array by eiter spliting the layer or saving as shape. clip the layer to that of the area....and i think that is it.

So the image below is a very zoomed in area. Based on the statement that the bees cover a 0.2Ha area the area of the circle are all 2000sqm. bees do fly in straight lines but not squares. interestingly i creared 4 different dxfs 2 for hives and two for areas covered. and just worked of these without splitting.

the centre point would be a hive. so you are looking in the range of (55x55)x2....a lot of bees if it is a square 600ha.